# Dynamo Db Delete duplicate Entry from Table

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a situation where i need to find the duplicates and remove them from DynamoDB ,here is the table situation :**itemID** , **CustomerID** , "Details".

I want to delete the entire record if a customer has duplicates items from DynamoDB.

Here is the table situation:

[image: CID]

In the above table i want to delete the 4th row which has a duplicate record with the row 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say anything else about the needs of your application. If this de-duplication is the only concern, I think the solution is easy - make (CustomerID, ItemID) the item's **key**. For example, CustomerID can be the hash key, ItemID the sort key. Then, when you update the item with a certain customerid and itemid - it will replace the existing item (if any) with the same key.

Note that my suggestion also means that a (c1, p1, Coffee) will replace an existing (c1, p1, Sugar) - I don't know if this something you wanted or not, as in your example the second mention of the same item also had the same "Details".

Comment: No I dont want that the thing is a customer can order many items but every item should be unique some how the Db has duplicated record just like above example, so i want to remove that record

Comment: Of course, the customer can order many items, which is why you'll have both customerid and itemid as the key of each item - e.g., customer c1 can order items p1, p2, and p3, and (c1,p1), (c1,p2) and (c1,p3) will be separate items. But if suddenly another (c1,p2) comes along, it will just replace the previous entry for (c1,p2) instead of inserting a second copy. Isn't this what you wanted?

Comment: No there are lot of records I just want some type of query to delete the existing records as there are more then 50 thousands record

Comment: How does having 50 thousand, or even 50 billion records, change what I suggested? I guess I simply don't understand your scenario. What did you think the item key would be in your database, if not what I suggested?

Comment: you are talking about altering the DB I want query or some sort of method to delete the existing records

Comment: If you want to alter the DB you'll need to read all of it (I can't give you details because I don't understand what your DB looks like - what is the key of the items!) - I don't understand how you can get around that. And if you intend to read all the data anyway, you can write it back in a new way, to make it easier to do the same thing next time.

Comment: Every item has a unique key with the CustomerID is primary key and Product ID is sort key

Comment: ּSo, this is exactly what I suggested as a solution... So I don't understand how your problem even exists - row 1 and 4 in your example would have the same key, so they can't both exist in your database... Adding row 4 would have replaced row 1, not keeping both.

Comment: Db is migrated from some where else and added limitations later